# What is the wrong with this .bat excuting FFmpeg command using variables?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch-file

I want to create a .bat file to run FFmpeg commands.
It worked good until I decided to use variables.

Here it is

```
SET file=C:\[My Files\.01Movie\video879.mp4
SET folder=C:\[My Files\.01Movie\

ffmpeg -i "%file%" -vf "fps=1/60,scale=960:-2" "%folder%\out%04d.jpg"
```

It worked as expected when I used absolute paths. This is the working

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\[My Files\.01Movie\video879.mp4" -vf "fps=1/60,scale=960:-2" "C:\[My Files\.01Movie\out%04d.jpg"
```

Comment: The .bat file executed the ffmpeg command with no problem when I used the full paths within the ffmpeg command. Post edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDos is not really understanding "%folder%\out%04d.jpg"

Because it sees this variable: %folder%\out% rather than %folder%. If you escape the % using the escape char: ^ it should work correctly.

So your batchfile becomes:

```
ffmpeg -i "%file%" -vf "fps=1/60,scale=960:-2" "%folder%\out^%04d.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha, It seems that ([) in my path was the problem. it turned out that I should escape it with \

Comment: That info was not in your post when I wrote my answer. Glad its solved though.

Comment: I came up with virtual path that represent the real one but I missed to place ([). Without your answer, I was still having a problem. Many thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. :) You can also use the ^ to escape in your path, given that \ is also used in a path and normally not to escape text.